# Props don't update value of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I am passing value to child component Field:

```
<Field key = {field.fieldName} fieldName = {field.fieldName} value = {field.value} 
getModField={this._getModField.bind(this)} />
```

And in Field state should be updated by props:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: this.props.value,
        fieldName: this.props.fieldName
    };
}
```

I updated values should be shown in another field:

```
<div className = "form-group" key = {this.props.fieldName} >
    <input className="col-sm-2 control-label" name={this.props.value}
           defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)} 
           ref={(input) => this._value = input} />
</div>
```

But in constructor of Field this line: 
`value: this.props.value,` 
doesn't update `value`. Only change of fieldName triggers change of `value`

[image]

I think it's somehow related to `key` prop.
What can be problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to update your component's state with latest props. The best place to do that is `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. You will get nextProps as an argument in this method based on which you can call setState with new values.

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    fieldName: nextProps.fieldName,
    value: nextProps.value
  });
}
```

additionally you can add a check to see if value and fieldName is changed in props or not. If not you can optimize to not re-render the Component.

Comment: yes, It helped to update the state, but `defaultValue={this.state.value}` in input field still remains empty. It only gets updated value when `fieldName` changes

Comment: to update a input element you need to pass `initialValue` instead of `defaultValue`. It only updates when fieldName is changed because you are setting key based on `fieldName` hence the component is changed.

Comment: It means if instead of fieldName I pass some other variable which is static (never changes), it means all other fields also won't never change. Is there a way of solving it?

Comment: Sorry, a correction here. initialValue is not a prop for input element. You can use defaultValue but that works only first time, when component is mounted. and value prop is the current value of input element but it doesn't re-render the input element. I usually form my input element's key by `value` attribute so that when i pass a new value it appears.